# Node not joining in cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm creating a cluster with multiple(2) nodes but the nodes are not being detected.

Node:-1

```
cluster.name: mycluster
node.name: NODE1
node.master: true
node.data: true
index.number_of_shards: 5
index.number_of_replicas: 1
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.0.2.4"]
```

Node:-2

```
cluster.name: mycluster
node.name: NODE2
node.master: false
node.data: true
index.number_of_shards: 5
index.number_of_replicas: 1
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.0.2.15"]
```

With this configuration first I start the master(node1) and the I start the slave(node2) but the slaves are not being detected

I'm able to ping 10.0.2.15 from master and vice versa..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to specifying the unicast hosts property you also need to set the `bind_host` property in the `elasticsearch.yml` file on each of your host and restart them. That's because ES [binds to localhost by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_network_changes.html#_bind_to_localhost) as can be seen in the log you posted, i.e. see boldified log below

> [2016-01-29 18:18:56,280][INFO ][cluster.service ] [Pixx] new_master {Pixx}{5wg_P7RdT0ykX1q4SAajCA}{**127.0.0.1**}{**127.0.0.1:9300**}{master=true}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)

So on node 1, you need this:

```
network.bind_host: 10.0.2.15
```

And on node 2 you need this:

```
network.bind_host: 10.0.2.4
```

Comment: Thanks...network.host: "_non_loopback_",  I added this and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable `multicast discovery`. Comment the configuration `discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false` or set this property to true in `elasticsearch.yml`

Comment: Tried that but still not being detected.I have set the property to True in both the nodes

Comment: You are using name.name = NODE1 to set the node name. Should'nt it be node.name=NODE1?

Comment: discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts should contain ip of master node in list. Is 10.0.2.15 ip ofyour master node?

Comment: Yes, 10.0.2.15 is my master node and its given in node2 - discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts

Comment: I think the problem is my node1 is starting using localhost parameter instead of its ipaddress, this causes the node2 unable to detect it

Comment: Here is the info from the log...[2016-01-29 18:18:56,280][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Pixx] new_master {Pixx}{5wg_P7RdT0ykX1q4SAajCA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{master=true}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just because first google results brings me here.

ES version 5.1.2

**network.host: 0.0.0.0**

Helped me to make nodes see each other.

More info: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/modules-network.html